# Marking location on a country map using Longitude/Latitude

Tags: javascript, svg, gis, d3.js, mercator

I am working on an application where I need to mark location of a person on India map using longitude/latitude. I will be using javascript (jQuery/D3) to do this. I have an svg map of India (http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/69/India_states_and_union_territories_map.svg) which I will be using as base map. How can I go about marking a GPS location (For Eg 25°46'27"N   75°24'1"E) on this map ? Also how do I know if this map is Mercator Projection map ?

Thanks and regards,
Vikalp Jain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map you want to use doesn't have any geographic information attached to it, i.e. you would have to translate geocoordinates to map coordinates manually. You might be better off using a GeoJSON file with data for India in it.

Have a look at the examples at the [D3 wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki) to get an idea how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. From where do I get GeoJSON file for India ?

Comment: You can find a GeoJSON file for the entire world [here](https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json) for example. You can extract India from that.